# Display a graph given (X,Y) tuple

Tags: javascript, css, html, graph

I have a set of (X,Y) tuples. I need to display a very basic, simple looking X-Y axis graph in my html page.

I am focusing on **simple and basic** here, because I found some resource for the same on net, some library, but it seemed very highly functional, having superb look-feel, not so easy to implement type of stuff.

Here's a simple expected type :

[image]

How can I do it using `HTML/Javascript/CSS`?

Comment: You can probably use canvas element to render your graph. But I think it is not available on older IE versions like 7 & 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See formal definition of tuple.
2. By using a canvas and some javascript. There's plenty of libraries around for doing this already, but the canvas is easy to use and you should have no trouble drawing the lines in the colours and locations you need.

Do use a library if you want the best looking/functioning output. Do learn how to do it yourself if you have other more highly valued aims.

Comment: that's xatly what i needed !

Comment: @Alnitak, I would argue that "a set of (X,Y) tuples" implies that the co-ordinates are the tuple and the list to be the container that holds them. In my understanding, an "ordered-pair" is the more appropriate term for the (x,y) co-ordinates. Using conventional notation, the X,Y pair would be known as a "2-tuple". Further research indicates that, yes, this is indeed known as an ordered pair. While further reading has led me to conclude that either are correct english, calling {x,y} a tuple is correct but somewhat misleading. (it's not usual to call pairs tuples). :shrug: